# Google and Facebook login url handlers in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, google-signin

So I've already integrated Google Sign in into my app and have the following function in my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // handled to go back to application after google log in
    let handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])

    return handled
}
```

Now I'm trying to add Facebook login and I'm supposed to add the following to that same function:

```
let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().handle(application(app, open: url, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication], annotations: options[:])
```

How can I deal with having two different `handled` variables that need to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

That's the way I found to manage both situations

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    let canHandleURL = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let canHandleGoogleUrl =  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)
    if canHandleURL {
        return true
    } else if canHandleGoogleUrl {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Following @JAL suggestion, you can optimize this code adding the following lines:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(applic‌​ation, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) || GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)

}
```

Comment: So are these two functions the same then pretty much? (The one I have and the one you put)

Comment: Why not just optimize this? `return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) || GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication!, annotation: annotation)`

Comment: Yes, they are pretty much the same and you can optimize them by doing what @JAL suggested.